# Power BI Matrix: Make a field appear in one column only

Tags: powerbi, visualization

In the matrix, in columns I have month names in level1, and 2 years (2022 and 2023) in level 2. Variance is the percentage change from 2022 to 2023. How can I make it appear only once (under 2023 and not under 2022)[The matrix in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCjCc.png)

I have tried making measures for 2022 and 2023 and removed year from columns but then the filtering stops working.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcOTQcMFmhc